Multiple dataframe explode for 4 flat lists in pandas
Description:
I have 4 lists that I would like to explode in the following order temps, volts, powers and freqs .
import pandas as pd
temps = [-20,60]
volts = [6.3, 7.4]
powers = [float(p) for p in range(15,35,5)]
freqs = [float(f) for f in range(100,120,10)]

Expected output:



temps
volts
powers
freqs




-20
6.3
15
100


-20
6.3
15
110


-20
6.3
20
100


-20
6.3
20
110


-20
6.3
25
100


-20
6.3
25
110


-20
6.3
30
100


-20
6.3
30
110


-20
7.4
15
100


-20
7.4
15
110


-20
7.4
20
100


-20
7.4
20
110


-20
7.4
25
100


-20
7.4
25
110


-20
7.4
30
100


-20
7.4
30
110


60
6.3
15
100


60
6.3
15
110


60
6.3
20
100


60
6.3
20
110


60
6.3
25
100


60
6.3
25
110


60
6.3
30
100


60
6.3
30
110


60
7.4
15
100


60
7.4
15
110


60
7.4
20
100


60
7.4
20
110


60
7.4
25
100


60
7.4
25
110


60
7.4
30
100


60
7.4
30
110



Need help with the following code:
df = pd.DataFrame({"temps":[temps], "volts": [volts], "powers": [powers], "freqs":[freqs]})
df.explode(df.columns.to_list())

Current error:
ValueError: columns must have matching element counts

Dirty work around the issue:
I've wrote a code that could do it for time being, however in the future I would need to add even more test cases, so this code will be causing issues:
nested_list = lambda N,data: [data for n in range(len(N))]
df = pd.DataFrame({"temps":temps, "volts": nested_list(temps,volts)})
df = df.explode(['volts'])
df["powers"] = nested_list(df.temps,powers)
df = df.explode(['powers'])
df["freqs"] = nested_list(df.temps,freqs)
df =  df.explode(['freqs']).reset_index(drop=True)


Use from  itertools import product and  df = pd.DataFrame(product(temps,volts, powers, freqs), columns=["temps", "volts", "powers", "freqs"])
